# Grails uglifyjs plugin does not work

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, uglifyjs

I have added uglifyjs plugin to my project with 
`grails install-plugin uglify-js-minified-resources`.

Also added `compile ":uglify-js-minified-resources:0.1.1"` to my `BuildConfig.groovy` file.

After starting application none of the js files was minified. Am i missing some configuration?
I was following [this](http://grails.org/plugin/uglify-js-minified-resources)

My BuildConfig file

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    mavenRepo "xxx"

}

dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    runtime 'org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:1.0.2'
    runtime 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9'
}

plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.2"
    compile ":grails-melody:1.45"
    compile ":uglify-js-minified-resources:0.1.1"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

    compile ':cache:1.0.1'

    if (Environment.current == Environment.PRODUCTION) {
        runtime ':ext-js-common:latest.release'
    }
}
```

}

my resourses file :

```
modules = { 
    css {
        dependsOn 'css-common'
        resource url:'css/test.css'
    }

    utils {
        dependsOn 'ext-js-core'
        resource url:'js/util/test.js'

    }

    plugins {
        dependsOn 'ext-js-core, ext-overrides, utils, plugins-common'
        resource url:'js/plugins/asde.js'
    }

    extensions {
        dependsOn 'ext-js-core, utils, ux-common'
        resource url:'js/ux/treecombo/Ext.TreeCombo.js'

    }

    stores {
        dependsOn 'ext-js-core, utils'
        resource url:'js/store/store.js'

    }

    ui {
        dependsOn 'ext-js-core, utils, ext-overrides, plugins, extensions, stores'
        resource url:'js/ui/tab.ui.js'
    }
```

}

my app.gsp file contains these modules:

```
    <r:require module="css"/>   
<r:require module="utils"/>
<r:require module="plugins"/>
<r:require module="extensions"/>
<r:require module="stores"/>
<r:require module="ui"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you have the resource plugin enabled for the environment you are checking. Many times I had it off in Dev on accident. Also you can turn on the logging to see what is happening. Add the following to your log4j config.

```
debug "org.grails.plugin.resource"
```

Also the minified resources will only show on the web page itself. And only if using the tags from the resource plugin.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to check if it is running and yes it is. The only problem left is how could i have a look to compressed code, because in firebug i can`t see any changes or compression done. What tags should i add to only see compressed code?

Comment: Use <r:require modules="jquery-ui, blueprint"/> in the gsp and you define modules in config or resource.groovy

Comment: i don`t use jquery-ui, so that module cannot be found. Maybe you know module name for uglifyjs only?

Comment: What modules have you configured in the resource plugin?  You may want to go through the resource plugin doc to make sure you have it all correct.

Comment: What module should i add to make it work? Because i have just configured my *.js files and thats all.

Comment: What ever module you put your JS files in.

Comment: Check my updated, i added those files to my question

Comment: Adding that tag should be working for you, are you getting any errors in the logs?

Comment: No errors, `Uglified javascript file [main.js] to [main.min.js] in 0.184 seconds. Reduced size by 33%` are returned for all js files. But in firebug files are showed as not minified.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: yes, `grails.resources.debug = true` in my `Config.groovy` was the reason why i was not seeing those files uglified. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a plugin then you need to write it in BuildConfig.groovy.

```
dependencies {  
   // dependency will be here.
}
plugins {
    compile ":uglify-js-minified-resources:0.1.1"
}
```

Enjoy..

Comment: i forgot to mention, that it is included in BuildConfig.groovy, not in Config.groovy, and it still does not work

Comment: Post you code of BuildConfig.groovy. How you define it in BuildConfig.groovy